# export as PDf, then Hyperlink that PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take update a sheet, export it as a pdf, and put a hyperlink to that PDF.
The issue is the hyperlink is not working. I can't find a guide on how to hyperlink with the location, and name to be both be variables and not fixed values.

I have tried .name and .value. Also just leaving it at strPathFIle. But always get an error on the address.

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myfile As Variant


Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet


'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = Worksheets("Control Sheet").Cells(1, 1).Value & "Sheets\"
If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"


'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "_")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")


'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile



'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myfile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPathFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If


Worksheets("Main Page").Activate

Dim Departments As Range
Dim dep As Range
Set Departments = Worksheets("Main Page").Range("a5:a7") 'make this much larger for final

For Each dep In Departments
        MsgBox wsA.Name & " & " & dep.Value
        If dep.Value = wsA.Name Then
            
        With Worksheets(1)
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=dep.Value, _
             Address:=strPathFile.Value, _
             ScreenTip:=wsA.Name, _
            TextToDisplay:=wsA.Name
        End With
            
            GoTo depgame
        End If
Next dep
MsgBox "this didnt work"
depgame:
```

Comment: `strPathFile` is a string, it has no `.value` property, not sure if that is your issue

Comment: Also `Anchor` requires a range or shape, `dep.value` is a string.